# SIM7000G Connectivity Issue

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using **[botletics / SIM7000-LTE-Shield](https://github.com/botletics/SIM7000-LTE-Shield)** with Arduino Uno. I ran LTE-Demo example with the following adjustments based on this **[source](https://halberdbastion.com/intelligence/mobile-networks/saudi-telecom-company-stc)**:

- fona.setNetworkSettings(F("**jawalnet.com.sa**"));
- fona.setPreferredMode(**2**);
- fona.setPreferredLTEMode(**3**);
- fona.setOperatingBand("**NB-IOT**", **12**);
- fona.enableRTC(**true**);

But I'm getting no where and there is no registered network. I even tried Band (**CAT-M**) with *no luck*

I'm powering the shield from UNO with no external battery. 2 Green leds are led + blue led is flashing

**Any Idea what am I doing wrong?**

```js
FONA basic test
Initializing....(May take several seconds)
Configuring to 9600 baud
Attempting to open comm with ATs
    ---> AT
    <--- AT
    ---> ATE0
    <--- ATE0
    ---> ATE0
    <--- OK
    ---> ATI
    <--- SIM7000G R1529

OK

    ---> AT+CPMS="SM","SM","SM"
    <--- +CPMS: 0,100,0,100,0,100
FONA is OK
Found SIM7000
    ---> AT+GSN
    <--- 869951031081155
Module IMEI: 869951031081155
    ---> AT+CFUN=1
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","jawalnet.com.sa"
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CNMP=2
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CMNB=3
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CBANDCFG="NB-IOT",12
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CLTS=1
    <--- OK
    ---> AT&W
    <--- OK
-------------------------------------
[?] Print this menu
[a] Read the ADC; 2.8V max for SIM800/808, 0V-VBAT for SIM7000 shield
[b] Read supply voltage
[C] Read the SIM CCID
[U] Unlock SIM with PIN code
[i] Read signal strength (RSSI)
[n] Get network status
[1] Get network connection info
[c] Make phone Call
[A] Get call status
[h] Hang up phone
[p] Pick up phone
[N] Number of SMSs
[r] Read SMS #
[R] Read all SMS
[d] Delete SMS #
[s] Send SMS
[u] Send USSD
[y] Enable local time stamp (SIM800/808/70X0)
[Y] Enable NTP time sync (SIM800/808/70X0)
[t] Get network time
[G] Enable cellular data
[g] Disable cellular data
[l] Query GSMLOC (2G)
[O] Turn GPS on (SIM808/5320/7XX0)
[o] Turn GPS off (SIM808/5320/7XX0)
[L] Query GPS location (SIM808/5320/7XX0)


-------------------------------------

FONA> C
    ---> AT+CCID
    <--- 8996601730099550895f
SIM CCID = 8996601730099550895f
FONA> n
    ---> AT+CREG?
    <--- +CREG: 0,2
Network status 2: Not registered (searching)
FONA> l
    ---> AT+CIPGSMLOC=1,1
    <--- ERROR
Failed!
Fail code #2
FONA> n
    ---> AT+CREG?
    <--- +CREG: 0,2
Network status 2: Not registered (searching)
FONA>  n
---> AT+CREG?
<--- 
Network status 0: Not registered
FONA>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @jsotola how to make it work?

Comment: Im working on a similar project and running into the same issue with the flashing blue network LED. Im guessing its cycling power since there is no battery for the shield. Guess ill have to wait until my battery arrives.